# If virtual particles is not real, what are the lines in Feynman diagram?

Tags: feynman-diagrams, virtual-particles

Since virtual particles is not real, than what are the curved lines in the Feynman diagram if it is not virtual particles?

Comment: In Feynman diagram, virtual particles are particles that are created after the start of the diagram and are destroyed before its end. Which curved lines are you referring to?

Comment: 1. Do you mean *internal* lines instead of curved lines? 2. Why do they have to "be" anything?

Comment: I think Bertel means the "[squiggly lines](http://www.quantumdiaries.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/QEDvertex.png)".

Answer (score 4):

Feynman diagrams are *calculational tools*. They are terms in a series expansion of the propagator depicted in a nice fashion. A Feynman diagram does not *exist* in a meaningful sense in the physical world. Thus yes, the curved lines which have no external lines are e.g. virtual photons in QED. This does not make them have any "realness". The contradiction you seem to be implying in your question does not exist.